# How can I configure the One UI Home app so that I can scroll down and up all the installed apps and have the first letter of the app on the right side

Tags: applications, samsung-one-ui, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I use a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra with Android 13 and One UI 5.1. On my iPhone 12 mini with iOS 15, I can scroll up and down through all the installed apps and have the first letter of each app displayed on the right side. This is convenient for quickly accessing the desired app:

[image]

How can I achieve the same functionality with the One UI Home app?

Comment: I don't think the One UI Home app provides that option, so the only answer is to use a 3rd-party launcher app...